# wp:shortcode works in block theme template file but not PHP include file

Tags: shortcode, templates, include

Block markup generally works in included PHP files. I prefer to use PHP includes in many cases as I can do more interesting things with it than I can with a template file (.html). I've just encountered an example where a macro works in a template file but not a PHP include: if I have the following content in a template file (let's call it `templates/single-custom.html`),

```
<!-- wp:shortcode -->[ai_playlist id="2276"]<!-- /wp:shortcode -->
```

the shortcode renders on the front end for the 'custom' post type. If, however, I have the following content in the template file,

```
<!-- wp:pattern {"slug":my-theme/hidden-my-include"} /-->
```

and then in `patterns/hidden-my-include` the same content,

```
<!-- wp:shortcode -->[ai_playlist id="2276"]<!-- /wp:shortcode -->
```

the output is the string,

```
[ai_playlist id="2276"]
```

I've fiddled with it a bit, and also tried,

```
<!-- wp:shortcode --><?php echo do_shortcode('[ai_playlist id="2276"]'); ?><!-- /wp:shortcode -->
```

in the include file, but it still just echoes the shortcode string (I've also tried `do_shortcode` without the wrapping `echo`).

Any ideas?

---

Edit:

I am going to leave the accepted answer, but others should know that the solution may or may not reintroduce a security vulnerability identified with rendering shortcodes in Block Themes: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/58333

Note that a workaround outlined by a user in the above-linked Trac issue is as follows (place in `functions.php`, or another included file in theme or plugin),

```
/*
Plugin Name: Fix shortcode
Plugin URI:
Description: Restore shortcode support on block templates https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/58333
Author: Anderson Martins, Gabriel Mariani
Version: 0.2.0
*/

function parse_inner_blocks(&$parsed_block)
{
    if (isset($parsed_block['innerBlocks'])) {
        foreach ($parsed_block['innerBlocks'] as $key => &$inner_block) {
            if (!empty($inner_block['innerContent'])) {
                foreach ($inner_block['innerContent'] as &$inner_content) {
                    if (empty($inner_content)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $inner_content = do_shortcode($inner_content);
                }
            }
            if (isset($inner_block['innerBlocks'])) {
                $inner_block = parse_inner_blocks($inner_block);
            }
        }
    }

    return $parsed_block;
}

add_filter('render_block_data', function ($parsed_block) {

    if (isset($parsed_block['innerContent'])) {
        foreach ($parsed_block['innerContent'] as &$inner_content) {
            if (empty($inner_content)) {
                continue;
            }

            $inner_content = do_shortcode($inner_content);
        }
    }

    $parsed_block = parse_inner_blocks($parsed_block);

    return $parsed_block;
}, 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario:**
Gutenberg Blocks -> page.html has wp: include  that includes a pattern file that has shortcode in it, the shortcode is not executed and comes back text only.

After reviewing and testing the above issue I realized the shorcode just does not run, I did find a workaround that allows the shortcode to run as expected.

**Solution:**
Created my own tag that does the work and is formatted close to the original

replace this:

```
<!-- wp:pattern {"slug":my-theme/hidden-my-include"} /-->
```

With this:

```
<!-- wp:shortcode --> [wpb_run_pattern  pattern="hidden-my-include"] <!-- /wp:shortcode -->
```

Then create a file in your /patterns/ folder called hidden-my-include.php

Then add this code to it:

```
<!-- wp:shortcode --> [wpb_run_misc_shortcode] <!-- /wp:shortcode -->
```

Then, in your functions.php file put this code and run your files:

```
function run_pattern_shortcode_from_block_func($atts) {
    if (!isset($atts['pattern']) || !is_string($atts['pattern'])) {
        return 'Invalid input.';
    }

    // Sanitize the input
    $pattern_name = sanitize_text_field($atts['pattern']);

    // Construct the file path using WordPress functions
    $file_path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/patterns/' . $pattern_name . '.php';

    // Check if file exists and is a PHP file
    if (file_exists($file_path) && pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'php') {
        $content = file_get_contents($file_path);

        $blocks = parse_blocks($content);
        $processed_content = '';

        foreach ($blocks as $block) {
            $block_content = render_block($block);
            $block_content = do_shortcode($block_content);
            $processed_content .= $block_content;
        }

        return $processed_content;
    } else {
        return 'File not found.';
    }
}
add_shortcode('wpb_run_pattern', 'run_pattern_shortcode_from_block_func');

function wpb_run_misc_shortcode_func() {
    // Example of escaping output
    return esc_html('Hello World !!!');
}
add_shortcode('wpb_run_misc_shortcode', 'wpb_run_misc_shortcode_func');
```

The shortcode in the patterns file ran as expected.

Comment: I appreciate the time you have put into this, but what you're effectively doing now is putting a shortcode in a file and feeding the contents of that file into `do_shortcode`. Maybe I haven't explained the situation well enough. My end goal is to parse the shortcode ID from the post meta and use that to render the appropriate shortcode. I cannot access post info from a template file, but I can from a `.php` include. Normally all the macros work when I do this, but doesn't for shortcode macro for some reason.

Comment: I understand what you are saying completely, but I did not see a solution to that problem, so I made it work just the same with proper security measures.
-----
I am parsing the file using the proper method that the template system does not seem to do for some reason. Maybe it iwll be updated in a future update

Comment: Okay, I've tinkered with it and get what you mean now. Excellent, thorough response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try naming the html file .php
templates/single-custom.php
Also
Remove the  and  comments from your PHP include file.
Directly use the do_shortcode() function to render the shortcode.
Here's the revised code for your PHP include:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ai_playlist id="2276"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Renaming the file `.php` defeats the file hierarchy of a block theme: everything in `templates/` should be an `.html` file. Those aren't vanilla HTML comments: they're WordPress macros for a block theme. With or without the macros, if `do_shortcode` is called in a PHP include file that is included in a block template file, the shortcode does not render as expected.

Comment: Renaming it to php would be a good way to test if that is the issue, or if it is something else. If that is the issue then you can research that.

Comment: The macro works in the template file (`.html`) but does not in the include file (`.php`). The `do_shortcode` function is also not working in the include file. If it did, I would happily use that instead of the macro.

Comment: I am looking in the theme files for the theme 2024 and all the files in the /patterns/ directory are using .php extensions. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am trying your code on my copy of wordpress now

Comment: Check out the `templates/` directory. Create a new template file, and in that put the pattern macro (e.g. `<!-- wp:pattern {"slug":my-theme/hidden-my-include"} /-->`). Then, in `my-theme/hidden-my-include.php`, put the shortcode macro (you'll have to use a different shortcode that exists in your installation).

Comment: I may have a solution, going to post it as another answer now, give me a few.

Comment: Try this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/421663/238918